# How to mix Angular with .ASP.NET Core MVC application?

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have ASP.NET Core MVC web application, and I want to have some pages (with complex UI) to be developed with Angular.

For example, I have a page that will show a list of customers (the routing done using ASP.NET Core MVC) on the URL: `/customer/index`, and the component which doing it is `app-show-customers`.

Another page (`/customer/edit/42`) is for editing customer using component `app-edit-customer`.

Both of these components inserted in `*.cshtml` view.

I do the following to bootstrap it

```
platformBrowserDynamic(providers).bootstrapModule(ShowCustomersModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
platformBrowserDynamic(providers).bootstrapModule(EditCustomerModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

It works for me.

The problem I have is one of the bootstrapping calls failing when the module not found on the page. It still works but giving the error in console.

> Error: The selector "app-edit-customer" did not match any elements

For example, when I open `/customer/index` to show all customers, the `EditCustomerModule` bootstrapping throws an error and vice versa.

I understand that is because the `app-edit-customer` component does not exist on `/customer/index`.

I feel like I am doing something wrong there, but I do not know what exactly. How are you usually use Angular with ASP.NET Core MVC applications when you want just some pages to be developed using Angular.

When working with AngularJS, that was not an issue, but I have a feeling Angular 2 can't be mixed with ASP.NET Core MVC and should be used just like a SPA.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you can, I would highly suggest having an .NET API and a front-end completly in Angular. It might be more work but it will be easier to scale your app using an API.

Comment: This is not answer, but somebody here proposes a way to mix ASP.NET MVC with Angular: https://www.infoq.com/articles/Angular-Core-3/